# Convert varchar to datetime SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to build a query that convert a varchar value with this format 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss' to datetime format. I actually tried with the following query

```
SELECT CAST(TSTAMP AS DATETIME) AS DATE
```

This gives me the following error:

*The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.*

Also with CONVERT function the error given is the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share sample data that is in varchar?

Comment: `set dateformat dmy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

SQL Server misinterprets the date time, because it thinks that it is in a different format. To fix this, use `CONVERT` with the optional third 'format' parameter.

```
CONVERT(DATE, TSTAMP, 103) -- 103 is dd/mm/yyyy
```

The other possibility is that the column contains a value which cannot be stored in the selected data type or makes no sense, such example would be `'13/13/2000'` which can in fact be stored in `VARCHAR`, but makes no sense as a `DATE`.

To catch these, you can try to use `TRY_CONVERT(DATE, TSTAMP, 103)` which will result in NULL where the date cannot be converted.

Further reading:
https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-functions-for-converting-string-to-date/

Answer (score 0):

Without providing the respective format, SQL Server may assume a wrong format for your string (based for instance on localization settings) so use the following

```
convert(date, '17/12/2021', 103)
```

See a list of available dateformats here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Though already the answer is accepted but I was intending to share my answer :)

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'30/08/2021',103) AS MyDate
```

It gives result like this:

[image]

Comment: *to share my answer* why? There are 2 answers with the same exact code posted 40 mins earlier.